# Print method For Java LinkedQueue not getting the front value

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

I implemented a LinkedQueue in Java. This is my own implementation, it doesn't extend any classes or implements any interfaces (project's requirements) 
However, my print method is not returning the first item in the queue. Any ideas why?

The ListNode class

```
public class ListNode<AnyType> {
    public ListNode( AnyType theElement ) {
            this( theElement, null );
        }
    public ListNode( AnyType theElement, ListNode<AnyType> n) {
        element = theElement; next = n;
        }

    public AnyType element;
    public ListNode next;
}
```

The LinkedQueue class

```
public class LinkedQueue <AnyType> {
    private ListNode<AnyType> front;
    private ListNode<AnyType> back;


    LinkedQueue() {
        front = back = null;
    }

    public void enqueue ( AnyType x ) {
        if ( isEmpty()) 
            back = front = new ListNode<AnyType>(x);
        else back = back.next = new ListNode<AnyType>(x);
    }
public LinkedQueueIterator<AnyType> first() {
        return new LinkedQueueIterator<AnyType>(front.next);
    }

    public static <AnyType> void printList(LinkedQueue theList) {
        if (theList.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Empty List");
        } else {
            LinkedQueueIterator<AnyType> itr = theList.first();
            for( ; itr.isValid(); itr.advance()) {
                System.out.print( itr.retrieve() + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

The LinkedQueueIterator class

```
public class LinkedQueueIterator<AnyType> {
    ListNode<AnyType> current;
    LinkedQueueIterator(ListNode<AnyType> theNode) {
        current = theNode;
    }

    public boolean isValid(){
        return current != null;
    }

    public AnyType retrieve(){
        return isValid() ? current.element : null;
    }

    public void advance() {
        if( isValid())
            current = current.next;
    }


}
```

I really can't see anything wrong with it, but if I do LQ.enqueue("A"), LQ.enqueue("B"), LQ.enqueue("C") and call printList, all I get is B C

Comment: theList.first() Add in for loop statement and remove the .first from theList

Comment: In LinkedQueue.first() you return front.next instead of front? Unless I'm misunderstanding. I also see you don't have a way of removing an element. You have the equivilent of push (enqueue), but no pop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your coding for a while, just because of your little mistake, your `first()` method returns the element after the front element, here in this piece of code:

```java
public LinkedQueueIterator<AnyType> first() {
        return new LinkedQueueIterator<AnyType>(front.next);
}
```

Because you want to get the first element of the queue, then it should be modified like this:

```java
public LinkedQueueIterator<AnyType> first() {
        return new LinkedQueueIterator<AnyType>(front);
}
```

Now your program should run properly.